# Let $f: A\to B$ and $g: C \to D$. Both $f $ and $g$ are bijective. Prove if $f=g$ then $B=D$.

Tags: functions

Studying for a final and have no clue how to go about this one.

Edit: Sorry, just included definitions. My friend think that you can say if A contains a, then because its a function there must be a b in B. And because f = g then there must be a b in D. Because g is injective there must be an a in C and therefore B = D. Would that work?

---

I included definitions :
[image]

Comment: Could you recite your definition of equality of functions?

Comment: Doesn't look like a true statement to me.

Comment: This will entirely depend on your definition of a function.

Comment: Does $f=g$ mean even their codomains are the same? So $B=D$?

Comment: This is not true if you are modelling functions in the usual way in set ttheory. It is true in category theory.

Comment: Sorry, just included definitions. My friend think that you can say if A contains a, then because its a function there must be a b in B. And because f = g then there must be a b in D. Because g is injective there must be an a in C and therefore B = D. Would that work?

@EricTowers

Answer (score 1):

Let $b\in B$. $ f$ is a surjection.

So, $\exists a\in A: f(a)=b$.

So, $(a,b)\in f.$

$f=g$. So, $(a,b)\in g \subset C\times D$. So, $b\in D.$  So $$B\subset D$$

Likewise$$D\subset B$$

And finally $B=D.\square$

Comment: why do you not need to use the definition of set equality or subset